# String split to the desired outcome

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split

I have got a column dataframe containing strings with this format:

```
0                      D/WB/M (L)
1                    DM, M/AM (C)
2                  D (RC), WB (R)
3                D (C), DM, M (C)
4          M (C), AM (LC), ST (C)
```

the desired outcome is the following:

```
0 [D L, WB L, M L]
1 [DM, M C, AM C]
2 [D R, D C, WB R]
3 [D C, DM, M C]
4 [M C, AM L, AM C, ST C]
```

have tried a few things but the farthest I have gone is far from my desired outcome:

```
a = df['position'].str.split(', ')
i = 0
p_ps = list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    p_ps.append(df['position'][i].split(', '))

i = 0
for i in range(len(p_ps)):
    j = 0
    for j in range(len(p_ps[i])):
        p_ps[i][j] = p_ps[i][j].replace('(','').replace(')','').split(' ')
i = 0
for i in range(len(p_ps)):
    j = 0
    for j in range(len(p_ps[i])):
        try:
            if len(p_ps[i][j][1]) > 1:
                c = list()
                for a in p_ps[i][j][1]:
                    c.append(a)
                p_ps[i][j][1] = c
        except:
            continue
i = 0
for i in range(len(p_ps)):
    j = 0
    for j in range(len(p_ps[i])):
        k = 0
        for k in range(len(p_ps[i][j])):
            if '/' in p_ps[i][j][k]:
                p_ps[i][j][k] = p_ps[i][j][k].split('/')
i = 0
for i in range(len(p_ps)):
    j = 0
    for j in range(len(p_ps[i])):
        if len(p_ps[i][j]) > 1:
            k = 0
            for k in range(len(p_ps[i][j])):
                if not isinstance(p_ps[i][j][k], list):
                    p_ps[i][j] = str(p_ps[i][j][0]) + str(p_ps[i][j][1])
```

as you can see, the outcome of this code doesn't really achieve anything

Comment: what is the rule in spliting? why does M (C), AM (LC), ST (C) => M C, AM L, AM C, ST C

Comment: What should the desired output be? A list? A string?

Comment: @Boendal If in the parenthesis there is more than one letter, each of the letters has to be matched with the text on the left split on the slash so M/AM (RC) = M R, M C, AM R, AM C

Comment: @SimonFink preferably a list but a string with commas is fine too, I can then split by comma and get the list

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Could you provide some background?

Comment: @Georgy it doesn't come from anywhere, it's a script I am writing if this is the purpose of your question.

Comment: What do those letters mean at least? I'm asking because it's possible that there is a much easier solution than yours or, for example, the one proposed in the current answer. In other words, I wanna know if your problem is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this works with the data you provided. And it looks like with the information provided in the comment it should do what you wanted.

```
import re

def find_elements_in_brackets(str):
    m = re.search('\((.+?)\)', str)
    adder = []
    if m:
        for c in m.group(1):
            adder.append(c)
    return adder

data = ["D/WB/M (L)","DM, M/AM (C)", "D (RC), WB (R)","D (C), DM, M (C)","M (C), AM (LC), ST (C)"]
output = []
for index, row in enumerate(data):
    output.append([])
    for element in row.split(","):
        elements_in_brackets = find_elements_in_brackets(element)
        if elements_in_brackets:
            for splitted in element.split("/"):
                for c in elements_in_brackets:
                    output[index].append((splitted.split("(")[0].strip()+ " "+ c).strip())
        else:
            output[index].append(element.strip())
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[['D L', 'WB L', 'M L'], ['DM', 'M C', 'AM C'], ['D R', 'D C', 'WB R'], ['D C', 'DM', 'M C'], ['M C', 'AM L', 'AM C', 'ST C']]
```